# Scrabble Grid Word Detection Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithms, pseudocode

I am building a scrabble game, and I have already a dictionary working.

When the user will place letters on grid, I need to check that all the words are valid. Which algorithm can I use or how can I go through each cell of that grid to validate which are words in an efficient way ?

I tried googling but most of search results are about filling the grid with words. What I need is different, since the user has placed letters and I only need to validate which are actual words and not.

Example game board is attached

[image]

Comment: Did you actually try a simple, straightforward brute-force implementation? In a comment below, you mentioned "performance"  - why? Do you really have requirements where such an implementation would not be sufficiently fast? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

To detect a 'word' start with the square in which a tile has been placed and check adjacent squares for tiles.

If a tile is found follow the squares in the same direction untill you reach an empty square.

Do this for all four directions.

Append right to the end of left and bottom to the end of top

Check each word > 1 letter against your dictionary of allowed words.

Repeat for each tile placed

special case for first word. check for 1 letter words.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Unlike Scrabble, in my game user can start making words from anywhere instead of centre cell,

Words will only be formed from left to right and top to bottom

So it means i'll be only moving to those 2 directions and then come back and move to 2nd cell and repeat same process, 

is nt it cost more performance ?

Comment: @RehanulHassan this algorithm does not start from the center cell, but from all the cells where the player has put a new tile.  It goes in 4 direction until an empty cell is found, only to find the start of the word that you have to check.  It you want the diagonals as well, up to you to complete this algorithm.  The only innefficiency is that one of the explored direction will be the same for all the new tiles placed, so you'll recheck several times the same word.  To avoid this, make a list of the starting position and direction to be used and eliminate the doubles before validating.

Comment: @RehanulHassan if this algorithm would not work for you, then your question needs to be completed with the missing elements.  A picture could help: show a board, with colored letters for the new ones that just have been placed, and show all the words that you would have to check.  It would then be easier to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Updated the post with an image, as you can see words can only start from top to bottom or left to right. thanks

Comment: @rehamulhassan those are the same rules as scrabble

Answer (score 2):

If you separate the problem into smaller pieces, you will see that this is not as hard. Note that since you did not post any code, I can't give you the direct answer, but I'll help you get started on breaking this problem down into its constituent parts.

First of all, whenever you encounter a "I need to check all items" type of problem, this always breaks down into two separate problems:

- How do I find all the items?
- How do I validate a single item?

Your case is no different:

- How do I find all the words on the board?
- How do I validate a single word?

The rest is simply iterating over the first bullet point's result and calling the second, i.e.

```
foreach(var word in FindAllWordsOnBoard())
{
    Validate(word);
}
```

Now we've broken down the problem, let's look at the constituent problems.

**Validating an item**

This one is trivial, assuming you have a list of all valid words (which you claim you do).

```
public bool Validate(string word)
{
    return myListOfAllWords.Contains(word); // note: case sensitivity?
}
```

**Finding all words on the board**

If you follow the Scrabble rules, there are a few things to note about words:

- Words are either vertical or horizontal but follow a given reading direction (horizontal = left-to-right, vertical = up-to-down)
- Words must be at least 2 letters long (as a single letter means you didn't add anything to the board. (**edit**: @Ewan is correct, the first placed word is an exception as it can be a single letter, see my below edit)
- Separate words cannot be adjacent to each other. When two words are adjacent to each other, all of their adjacent letters must be valid words themselves (thus making them words as well)

This makes it fairly straightforward on how to find all words on a board:

- **edit** Due to the one-letter-exception (see above), if the entire board contains only one character, follow the following logic. Otherwise, continue to the next bullet points.

  - Is the one letter on the middle tile?
  - Is the one letter a valid word?
  - If one of these checks fails, then the board is not valid.
- Iterate over all rows, then iterate over all columns.
- For each row/column, look for all text entries that are at least 2 characters long, and are delimited **on both sides** by either a blank tile or a board edge

And those are all the words on the board. How you implement this logic heavily depends on how you store the board data, which you did not specify in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer :)